# Laravel $request->expectsJson() devuelve false

Tags: php, laravel

En mi login de mi web Laravel a la hora de hacer el Auth::attempt($credenciales) en mi logincontroller, dentro la funcion redirectTo() ha un if que comprueba si es un Json lo que se envia por el Auth, este último me devuelve false siempre y no se cmo enviarle un Json al Auth, mis credenciales se meten a traves de un array sencillo, he visto que puede solucionarse añadiendo un header "accept", pero nos e como añadirlo ni donde, os dejo unos fragmentos de código:

Routes:

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('inicio');
})->name('inicio');

Route::get('/quienes-somos', function () {
    return view('quienes-somos');
})->name('quienes-somos');

Route::get('/iniciar-sesion', function() {
    return view('auth.inicio-de-sesion');
})->name('admin.get.iniciar-sesion');

Route::group(['prefix' => 'administracion'], function () {
    
    Route::post('/cerrar-sesion', [LoginController::class, 'cerrarSesion'])->name('admin.post.cerrar-sesion');

    //Recuperar contraseña
    Route::get('/recuperar-contraseña/{id}/{token}', [UsuarioController::class, 'recuperarContraseña'])->name('admin.get.recuperar-contraseña');

    //Parte privada de la aplicación
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::post('/iniciar-sesion',[LoginController::class, 'iniciarSesion'])->name('admin.post.iniciar-sesion');
        Route::view('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('core.get.dashboard');
        Route::view('/editores', 'core.editores')->name('core.get.editores');
        Route::view('/articulos', 'core.articulos')->name('core.get.articulos');
        Route::view('/articulos/añadir', 'core.añadir-articulo')->name('core.get.añadir-articulo');
        Route::view('/equipo', 'core.equipo')->name('core.get.equipo');
        Route::view('/equipo/añadir', 'core.añadir-equipo')->name('core.get.añadir-equipo');

        Route::view('/suscriptores', 'core.suscriptores')->name('core.get.suscriptores');


    });
});
```

Authenticate.php

```
    class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('admin.get.iniciar-sesion');
        }
    }
}
```

Logincontroller

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{


    public function iniciarSesion(Request $request)
    {
        $credenciales = array(
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->contraseña
        );
        if (Auth::attempt($credenciales)) {
            // Authentication passed...;
            return "SI";
            return redirect()->route('core.get.dashboard');
            
        }
        //La autenticación no ha funcionado
        return "NO";
    }

    public function cerrarSesion()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->intended('inicio');
    }
    //
}
```

Form

```
<form class="mt-8" action="{{ route('admin.post.iniciar-sesion') }}" method="post">
        @csrf
        <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
            <div class="mt-4">
                <label for="email" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Correo electrónico</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" type="email" required placeholder="Correo electrónico" class="appearance rounded relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900  focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4">
                <div class="flex justify-between">
                    <label for="contraseña" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Contraseña</label>
                    <a href="{{ route('admin.get.he-olvidado-mi-contraseña') }}"
                        class="font-medium text-xs text-brand-600 hover:text-brand-500 focus:outline-none focus:underline transition ease-in-out duration-150">
                        Contraseña olvidada?
                    </a>
                </div>
                <input id="contraseña" name="contraseña" value="{{ old('password') }}" type="text" required placeholder="******" class="appearance-none rounded relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue focus:border-blue-300 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
            </div>
        </div>

            <button type="submit"class="group relative w-full mt-6 flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm leading-5 font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-brand-600 hover:bg-brand-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-brand-700 focus:shadow-outline-brand active:bg-brand-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">
                Iniciar sesión
            </button>


    </form>
```

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Comment: si necesitas devolver la credenciales no sobrescribas el metodo redirectTo porque esto es una peticion a la vista, intenta sobrescribir el metodo authenticated y alli devuelves las credenciales

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por responder, he implementado el metodo autheticated pero no me ha funcionado como esperaba. Ahora mismo estoy usando Imsomnia para las request, y ahi he podido ponerle el header, ¿Esto es algo temporal? ¿Como puedo introducir ese header en mi proyecto para siempre?

Comment: según veo estas metiendo la ruta login dentro del middleware auth, por eso no llega nada ya que se valida la sesion al no tener nada ni siquiera entra el metodo, debes sacar esa ruta del middleware group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Antes que nada:** tu formulario envía el usuario y password a `/administracion/iniciar-sesion`, pero esa ruta está declarada en un grupo que valida si el request está autenticado:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
    Route::post('/iniciar-sesion',[LoginController::class, 'iniciarSesion'])
       ->name('admin.post.iniciar-sesion');
    // otras rutas...
 });
```

Nadie puede loguearse porque el middleware los redirige justamente adonde empezaron. Debieras sacar la ruta de ahí y ponerla junto a la ruta `GET /iniciar-sesion`.

#### Con respecto al envío de JSON

El sentido de retornar la ruta al login sólo si el request no espera un JSON como respuesta es porque a un cliente de API (como Postman) o una petición fetch/xhr, no le sirve de nada si lo rediriges y termina recibiendo el HTML de la página de login. Si quieres informarle que debe loguearse lo correcto es devolver el header 401 y un mensaje indicando el por qué.

El middleware `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` extiende de `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate`,y su método `redirectTo` te permite definir **dónde redirigir, pero no determinar si se debe o no redirigir.**. La salida del método, sea cual sea,  se usa como argumento para tirar una excepción `\Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException`.

Esa excepción es manejada por el handler que está en `App\Exceptions\Handler`, el cual  extiende de [Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php). En un momento, ese handler define cómo renderizar la excepción dependiendo de su tipo. En este caso, esa renderización está en  [Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L382-L394):

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                : redirect()->guest($exception->redirectTo() ?? route('login'));
}
```

Qué significa esto? Que el handler de excepciones es quien define si redirigir o devolver un json con header 401.

De todos modos, respondiendo a tu pregunta, si quieres enviar el usuario y password como JSON y recibir json de vuelta en vez de redirección, tendrías que interceptar el envío del formulario y a cambio llamar a un script como

```
fetch("/administracion/iniciar-sesion", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "body": JSON.stringify({email:'ejemplo@mail.com','contraseña':'ejemplo123'}),
  "method": "POST"
});
```

esto puedes probarlo en la consola del browser desde ya, y así aprovechas de ver si el uso de la `ñ` no genera un segundo problema.